# how do I insert text at cursor position in textfield?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a custom keyboard, fixed on screen, that binds to a textfield. the textfield is read only.
The only problem is that, when I move the cursor inside the textfield, whatever I type is added to the end of the string, not considering the cursor position, which moves again at the start of the field. How can I fix this?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  var w;
  var limit;
  var textFieldHint;
  var minL;
  var maxL;
  var cont;
  var kbtype;
  var dispCursor;
  CustomTextField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.w,
      required this.limit,
      required this.textFieldHint,
      required this.minL,
      required this.maxL,
      required this.cont,
      required this.kbtype,
      required this.dispCursor})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * w,
          child: TextField(
            showCursor: dispCursor,
            controller: cont,
            keyboardType: kbtype,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: textFieldHint,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
            inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(limit),
            ],
            minLines: minL,
            maxLines: maxL,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the numpad button

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const CustomButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, right: 3),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.text += number.toString();
        },
        child: Text(
          number.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
        ),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(10),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.square(40)),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is where I am using it all

````
import 'package:expensetracker/Screens/home.dart';
import 'package:expensetracker/Widgets/customButton.dart';
import 'package:expensetracker/Widgets/customDate.dart';
import 'package:expensetracker/Widgets/customTime.dart';
import 'package:expensetracker/Widgets/customTextField.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddScreen> createState() => _AddScreenState();
}

var choice = [textConst.income, textConst.expense];
var dropdownvalue = textConst.income;
late DateTime _selectedDate;
TextEditingController title = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController descrip = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController amount = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController date = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController time = TextEditingController();

class _AddScreenState extends State<AddScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: ...
...CustomTextField(
                dispCursor: true,
                kbtype: TextInputType.none,
                cont: amount,
                // context: context,
                w: .8,
                limit: null,
                textFieldHint: textConst.amount,
                minL: 1,
                maxL: 1),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomButton(
                  number: 1,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  number: 2,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  number: 3,
                  controller: amount,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomButton(number: 4, controller: amount),
                CustomButton(number: 5, controller: amount),
                CustomButton(
                  number: 6,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomButton(
                  number: 7,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  number: 8,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  number: 9,
                  controller: amount,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomButton(
                  number: 0,
                  controller: amount,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      amount.text =
                          amount.text.substring(0, amount.text.length - 1);
                    },
                    child: Text(textConst.delete),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(10),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      // fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      //   Size.square(60),
                      // ),
                      minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Size(120, 40),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                    ))
              ],
            )```
````

Comment: Present your code.

Comment: It might be too much to comment here, can I share the github repo link to you?

Comment: Just the relevant code associated with the TextField and TextEditingController of course, not your entire app.

Comment: I have added the code of widget that I am using.

Comment: add how you use it too

Comment: done, you may see.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

To get the current position

```
if(_textEditingController.text.length > 0)
{
var cursorPos = _textEditingController.selection.base.offset;

String textAfterCursor =  _textEditingController.text.substring(cursorPos);

 String textBeforeCursor = _textEditingController.text.substring(0, cursorPos);
  _textEditingController.text = textBeforeCursor + "someText" + textAfterCursor;
                    
 _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 
 _textEditingController.text.length);
}
```

Here controller is the TextEditingController assigned to the textfield.

Comment: RangeError (start): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -1
Kaushik, this is the error I get